# How to stop htaccess rewrite rule carrying over query string

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I am setting up some redirects. I want to redirect the following URL:

```
/cms/index.php?cat_id=2
```

to the following URL:

```
/flash-chromatography
```

The rule I currently have is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat_id=2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^cms/index\.php$ /flash-chromatography [L,R=301]
```

This rule is almost perfect apart from it redirect the URL to the following:

```
/flash-chromatography?cat_id=2
```

So you see my problem is it has kept the `?cat_id=2` part when I don't want it to.

How do I stop it keeping this bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add `?` at the end of rewritten URL:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat_id=2$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^cms/index\.php$ /flash-chromatography? [L,R=301]
```